# Remove rows with same keys

Tags: ssis, rows

I have data with rows like the following:

```
Name1  Name2  Name3  Col  
aaa    bbb    ccc    ...  
abc    ddd    ddd    1  
abc    ddd    ddd    2  
abc    ddd    ddd    3  
fff    fff    fff    ...  
ggg    ggg    hhh    4  
ggg    ggg    hhh    5
```

(`Name1`, `Name2` and `Name3` are primary keys)

How do I remove the first rows from the set of data with the same 3 primary keys? (leaving *only* the last row of the set)

I.e. the result from the above would be:

```
Name1  Name2  Name3  Col  
aaa    bbb    ccc    ...  
abc    ddd    ddd    3  
fff    fff    fff    ...  
ggg    ggg    hhh    5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your source data is in the correct order, and you want the *last* record in each set, there aren't any out-of-the-box transformations that would handle this situation. However, a Script Transformation can deal with it fairly easily.

Here's a sample Data Flow:

[image]

I'm using `FF_SRC_AllRows` and `FF_DST_SelectedRows` as flat file source and destination (respectively) for simplicity's sake, using the sample data you provided; your specific needs will vary. The script transformation `SCR_SelectLastRow` is configured as a transformation (both input and output):

[image]

Select all your input columns (with usage type `ReadOnly`):

[image]

Create one output (I named mine `OutgoingRows`, but you can name it whatever you wish), and set the `SynchronousInputID` property to `None`. This will let your script filter out the rows you don't want.

[image]

Add output columns corresponding to the input columns:

[image]

And use code along these lines:

```cs
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    class IncomingRowData
    {
        public string Name1;
        public string Name2;
        public string Name3;
        public string Col;
        public IncomingRowData(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
        {
            Name1 = Row.Name1;
            Name2 = Row.Name2;
            Name3 = Row.Name3;
            Col = Row.Col;
        }
        public bool KeysDiffer(IncomingRowData other)
        {
            return (Name1 != other.Name1
                || Name2 != other.Name2
                || Name3 != other.Name3);
        }
        public void WriteToOutputBuffer(OutgoingRowsBuffer Row)
        {
            Row.AddRow();
            Row.Name1 = Name1;
            Row.Name2 = Name2;
            Row.Name3 = Name3;
            Row.Col = Col;
        }
    }

    private IncomingRowData _previousRow;

    public override void IncomingRows_ProcessInputRow(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
    {
        if (_previousRow == null)
        {
            _previousRow = new IncomingRowData(Row);
        }
        IncomingRowData currentRow = new IncomingRowData(Row);
        if (currentRow.KeysDiffer(_previousRow))
        {
            _previousRow.WriteToOutputBuffer(this.OutgoingRowsBuffer);
        }
        _previousRow = currentRow;
    }

    public override void FinishOutputs()
    {
        if (_previousRow != null)
        {
            _previousRow.WriteToOutputBuffer(this.OutgoingRowsBuffer);
        }
        base.FinishOutputs();
    }
}
```

One nice thing about this technique is that it allows you to handle the data in a single pass and requires neither the use of staging tables nor keeping the entire source data set in memory. Depending on how big your data set is, either of those could cause significant performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses!  I used Edmund Schweppe's answer, and my program worked!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation #1: Do this in your source query if at all possible.

Assuming that's not possible, *and* assuming that you always want the maximum value for Col to be selected, you can use the Aggregate component in your data flow.

Just add all of your columns to the aggregate input, and for the operations choose "Group By" for Name1, Name2, and Name3, and "Maximum" for Col.

Unfortunately, the aggregate component is an asynchronous component - meaning your entire flow will pause while the data flows into it, because it won't know the "maximum" value of each set until it's read in every row.

Comment: True; however, the OP was looking to get the *last* row, not the row with the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name1, 
       name2, 
       name3, 
       col 
FROM   (SELECT name1, 
               name2, 
               name3, 
               col, 
               Max(rn) 
                 over ( 
                   PARTITION BY name1, name2, name3 ) AS max_rn, 
               rn 
        FROM   (SELECT name1, 
                       name2, 
                       name3, 
                       col, 
                       Row_number() 
                         over ( 
                           PARTITION BY name1, name2, name3 
                           ORDER BY col ) AS rn 
                FROM   test1)) 
WHERE  max_rn = rn;
```

You can try this where test1 is tablename

Comment: I like the use of `PARTITION BY`. However, the OP asked for the *last* row, not the one with the *largest* value of `col`. Further, while the odds are pretty good that there's a SQL Server database somewhere in the OP's environment, the original question doesn't mention a database at all, let alone one that supports `PARTITION BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your data and select max Col value.

FLOW:

[image]

Data:

[image]

Aggregate element:

[image]

Result:
[image]

If you using SQL Table and can write query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54d13/1)**

```
SELECT Name1, Name2, Name3, MAX(Col) Col
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name1, Name2, Name3
```

Result:

```
| NAME1 | NAME2 | NAME3 | COL |
-------------------------------
|   aaa |   bbb |   ccc | ... |
|   abc |   ddd |   ddd |   3 |
|   fff |   fff |   fff | ... |
|   ggg |   ggg |   hhh |   5 |
```